# DB design issue

Tags: database, database-design

Our database includes a USERS table for storing user-specific data, and each user has a status, either `active` or `inactive`. It suffices to indicate the status using a `is_active` boolean field in the USERS table.

At the same time, for "inactive" users, we keep additional information in another field, which is irrelevant (and therefore set to null) for users in the opposite ("active") status.

My question: Is it a better design to keep the `is_active` boolean field in the USERS table to clearly indicate the status, or actually derive the status based on the available secondary criteria (the availability of the additional info, which is present always and only if the user is in status "inactive")?

That is, it looks like the `is_active` field is redundant with regards to DB normalization, but at the same time, the logic that can be used for deriving it isn't so obvious at first grasp and that makes queries concerning the status seem cumbersome and containing non-explicit logic.

Comment: Depends on what your end goal is.   I don't think it makes it significantly less normalized having the is_active field because you aren't repeating data across tables.   Also, it makes it much easier to interact with the database to have one field that  you can check the status of to see if a user is active.   It also avoids problems of having the additional fields not get updated when a user is inactivated (assuming the is_active field is not null).    But then I was always taught that third normal form is a good trade off point between application performance and data integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I'd prefer to have a specific flag for this, for the various reasons explained by others.

But apart from that... do you have queries that specifically include only one of the two types (e.g. "list of users that are inactive and have been created more than one year ago" or "send an email to all active users that haven't logged in in the last month")?

If yes, an index on (or including) the field will surely be more efficient.

I think that it could be a good idea not to make this boolean, either, in case you lately find out that you need to model a third or fourth "kind" of users.

Answer (score 2):

If someone went inactive and then later became active again, the other field could still be filled in, Keep the is_active field.

Comment: @pheedbaq, one thing I notice about non-database specialists who are designing datbases or stabase objects, they often forget to consider how the data will need to be maintained or change over time in the design.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to store and use data about activity.  In some applications, that might be payments. In others it might be last login time. (Data about inactivity isn't what I'm talking about.)

Next best is an explicit flag. But Boolean data types don't have enough distinct values (duh) for some query optimizers to do better than a full table scan on a Boolean column. Some dbms support partial indexes or function-based indexes that can improve performance on Booleans; use that if you use a flag and if your dbms supports it.

Flags look like data, but often they're a kind of pseudo-data.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Is_Active field. Databases have a way of changing to suit needs that arise over time. Who knows, you might want to use the irrelevant field to store information about active users.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar fields in my DBs that are useful to end-users just so they can get an idea of what's going on at a glance.  If your DBMS supports it, I'd make is_active a computed field (based on your inactive criteria) with an index on it.  You might have to make a user-defined function that the computed field refers to, which could prevent placing an index on it, but I think you should avoid using the computed field as criteria in queries anyway.

Make a view that contains your criteria for inactive records, and returns the PKs of all the records it applies to.  Then use that view as the 1 place to go to for any queries that need the criteria.  If performance gets to be an issue you can look at indexing the view to speed things up.